# Angular Router Events: NavigationEnd -- How to filter only the last event

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I want to extract **only the last event entry of type NavigationEnd** from router.events. But somehow I can't find a proper way to do this. Whatever I try the following code snipped is the only way to get access to these objects of interest.

```
let ne: any;

router.events.filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd)
   .forEach(e => {
      ne = e as NavigationEnd;                 
   });

console.log('target page: ', ne.urlAfterRedirects);
```

But do I really have to use .forEach() letting it run though all entries and using then the last entry? Isn't there a better way to handle the events as a kind of array and then say

```
ne = arrayOfEvents[arrayOfEvents.length-1]
```

?

I'm getting crazy about it but it seems that I can't see the wood for the trees...

Comment: Have you looked at using the `last` operator on observables? http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/last.html

Comment: Yes, I tried it. But it unfortunately doesn't work in my case as there is no processable return value.

Comment: Did you see this article? https://toddmotto.com/dynamic-page-titles-angular-2-router-events

Comment: That's it! This helps a lot. Thank you.

Comment: If the events observable never completes then `last` never does anything. What do *you* mean by last? **YOU** mean the last in the group. But the computer can wait 100 years for the stream to close, and that's what `last()` means to RxJS! So I think actually `last()` will NEVER return (it possibly might as the page is being unloaded but that's no use).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, after reading through the posted articles above and rethinking what I really want to achieve I found out that my approach was definitely too complicated. Because actually I only need access to the currently called route. And so I started from scratch and came across this small but very effective solution:

```
this.router.events.subscribe(value => {
    console.log('current route: ', this.router.url.toString());
});
```

Thanks to all who shared a comment in oder to support me! It helped al lot as I was able to tie up loose ends.

Comment: Since angular 12 this is deprecated! Use this instead:
this.router.events.pipe(filter((event): event is NavigationEnd => event instanceof NavigationEnd)).forEach(next => {
});

Answer (score 60):

PS. There's a better way to filter using an [instanceof typeguard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#instanceof-type-guards), you then get the proper type without having to assert it again:

```js
this.firstChildData$ = this.router.events.pipe(
  filter((e): e is NavigationEnd => e instanceof NavigationEnd),
  map(e => {
    // e is now NavigationEnd
  })
);
```

[image]

Comment: Also I recommend putting this in a global service with `shareReplay(1)` at the end. Sometimes I found a need to detect a navigation that has already happened and by the time my component was created it was too late. This also lets you group together everything in one place that you may need to use elsewhere.

Comment: * `shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: true })` is better

Answer (score 3):

If you are using ngrx effect then you can create a effect that listen to router event:

```
import { NavigationEnd, Router } from '@angular/router';

routeTo$ = createEffect(
    () =>
        this.router.events.pipe(
            filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
            withLatestFrom(this.observable1$, this.observable1$),
            tap(([routerEvent, observable11Value, observable12Value]) => {
                if (this.router.url.includes(observable11Value) && !this.router.url.includes(observable12Value)) {
                    this.router.navigate([`/home/${observable11Value}`]);
                }
            })
        ),
    { dispatch: false }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.router.events.subscribe(value => {
        if(value instanceof NavigationEnd)    
          console.log(this.router.url.toString());
        });
```

Comment: Please explain how this would solve the problem.